# DDoS атака с помощью php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, я интересуюсь просто в познавательных целях, возможно ли создать код который будет совершать атаки на другой комп на основе `php`?

Comment: DDoS - с одного компа и php - точно нет)) Почитайте про DDoS вообще сначала.

Comment: дайте мне ботнет и я хоть на JS сделаю :DDD

Comment: Ботнету можно и телнетом команду дать)

Comment: Первая D в DDoS и означает, что у вас больше чем 1 компьютер)

Comment: Скорее вы серверу, где запускаете скрипт - устроите ддос атаку)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно, но смотря какой вид атаки. можно например пофлудить, или же отправлять еще какие нибудь многочисленные запросы

[DDOS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DoS-%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: > пофлудить, или же отправлять еще какие нибудь многочисленные запросы

Это DoS. С одного компа можно заддосить только кассовый аппарат.

Comment: @Sh4dow, ну у меня получалось таким способом и сайты ложить ;)

Comment: Так да, но DoS и DDoS не есть одно и то же. У вас видимо одинаковое с ТСом видение этого вопроса)

Comment: @Sh4dow, хмм, спасибо, буду знать, просто википедия дала результат только по запросу DoS, что меня немного насторожило. но прочитав немного внимательней (второй абзац), все стало ясно

Answer (score 2):

Да, конечно возможно. Открываем ip адрес средствами **fsockopen** и бомбим через **fwrite** мусором, можно с задержкой, можно без. Но, конечно, толку особо не будет, если слабая машина)